# LatePoint - 2 Agents at 1 location

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using LatePoint plugin for Wordpress, which is reservation software where you can define your agents, type of service and location. In settings there is a option to check that one agent cannot be at two locations at the same time. Does anyone know if or how to do the same thing for locations? I would like to have only one agent in one location at the same time. Now you can reserve 2 agents to one location and thats actually big problem for me.

Thanks for your replies

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkN5X.png)